# test not failing using chai assert with intern

Tags: javascript, chai, intern

I am using intern for UI test automation. I have a test where entering invalid user name results in the test failing. However, my test is not failing when it should.

Steps i want to automate:

1. enter username
2. click next button
3. check if password textbox is shown ( password text box is only shown if username is valid else remain on the same page)

Here is My Code:

Page Object script:

```
   enterLoginName: function (username) {
        console.log('entering username');
        return this.remote
            .findById(this.locator.uname).clearValue().sleep(1000)
            .type(username)
            .end().then(function () {
                console.log('username entered ');
            })
            .findById(this.locator.nextbtn).sleep(1000)
            .click().end(); // enter login name and click next button
    },
    isValidUsername:function() {
        console.log('checking if password textbox is displayed');
        return this.remote
            .findDisplayedById(this.locator.pwd).isDisplayed();
             //passowd test box is only shown if username is valid
    },
```

Test Script:

```
       'correct login name lands to password page': function () {

            loginPage.enterLoginName('ss').then(function () {
                loginPage.isValidUsername().then(function (pass) {
                    console.log(pass);

                }, function (fail) {
                 // code reaches here since password test box is not displayed
                    console.log('user name uas valid , enter password panel not was shown');
                    assert.fail(0, 1, 'Exception not thrown');// test not failing
                });

            })
```

Can someone please explain what is not working here and how to make it work properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the `loginPage` promise chain:

```
return loginPage.enterLoginName('ss')...
```

Comment: i dont understand . can you explain??

Comment: In your test script, you're calling functions that are asynchronous and that return Promises (or Promise-like objects), like `loginPage.enterLoginName`. When using Promises in tests, you need to 1) return the end of the Promise chain so that Intern can tell when the async operation is complete, and 2) make sure you return any Promises generated in `then` callbacks to ensure that _all_ async operations are observed. So you need `return loginPage.enterLoginName` at the outer level, and `return loginPage.isValidUsername` in the `then` callback.